# Vuej.js; Крашится Chrome при дебаге

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, phpstorm, отладка

У меня возникли проблемы с select в vue, даже в простейшем примере.
Я создаю проект с помощью команды `vue init webpack-simple`. 
Ничего не создаю, просто редактирую исходный App.vue к следующему виду
App.vue:

```js
<template>
        <div id="app">
            <div class="Test">
                <div style="padding: 10px">
                    <select name="LeaveType" v-model="selectData" @change="selectAction">
                        <option>First</option>
                        <option>Second</option>
                        <option>Third</option>
                        <option>Fourth</option>
                    </select>
                    selectData = {{selectData}}
                </div>
                <div style="padding: 10px">
                    <input v-model="inputData" >
                    inputData = {{inputData}}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>

        export default {
            name: 'app',

            data() {
                return {
                    selectData: "Second",
                    inputData: "hello"
                }
            },
            props: {},
            watch: {
                selectData: function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("watch selectData ( newValue = ", newValue, " )");
                },
                inputData: function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("watch inputData ( newValue = ", newValue, " )");
                },
            },
            methods: {
                selectAction() {
                    console.log("selectAction");
                },
                inputAction() {
                    console.log("inputAction");
                }
            },


        }
    </script>

    <style>
        #app {
            font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            text-align: center;
            color: #2c3e50;
            margin-top: 60px;
        }

        h1, h2 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        a {
            color: #42b983;
        }
    </style>
```

запускаю сервер `npm run dev`

Когда я начинаю дебажить данный код(с помощью PhpStorm или chrome devtools, неважно), поставив точки останова на строчки с `console.log`. Изменив в браузере select я попадаю на мои точки останова.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В метод selectAction и в **watch - selectData** , но, если нажать F9, т.е. далее, то падает страница браузера.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Т.е. любой дебаг, вызванный **select**'ом вызывает падение страницы.
Причем, без дебага страница не падает, все работает нормально, ни одной ошибки в консоль не выводится.
Так же Watch связанный с **input** отрабатывает без падений, как в режиме дебага, так и без него.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Пробовал на 2х компьютерах, на винде и на убунте, результат одинаковый.

### [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-fire-mgnjj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: webpack-simple уже давно мертво

Comment: @swartex, не подскажете как сейчас правильно создавать проект?

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/installation.html

Comment: @Swartex, обновил vue cli, создал проект через vue create, то же самое...

Comment: вместо точек остановки, попробуйте написать слово `debugger`. Сообщите о результатах

Comment: @Дмытрык, Я тут выяснил следующее. Я перенес всю логику в один файл, https://pastebin.com/GEvHwVCV. Установил на виртуалку хром 76й версии, и все работает отлично, как в дебаге, так и без. Потом обновил до 79( последняя на данный момент) и опять появилась данная ошибка. Осмелюсь предположить, что это ошибка в хроме.